# Apache 2.4 X-Forwarded-For for remoteip

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, x-forwarded-for

I configured apache 2.4 with following file

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/remoteip.conf`

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For 
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1
```

But It will not include header in tomcat.

Tomcat server.xml

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" requestAttributesEnabled="true" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"  protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" internalProxies="127\.0\.[0–1]\.1"/>
```

Comment: Try adding your network interface address as well as 127.0.0.1 as Tomcat might be seeing requesting traffic from there.

Comment: conf-available is not equal to conf-enabled

Comment: Ok,I created link. Still not working